# Curses set bright and dark backgrounds

Tags: python, macos, colors, curses

For this, it might be useful to note that I'm running python on a Mac in `xterm-color`

I'm trying to build a chess game with curses in Python, but I can't figure out how to set the color pairs to use bright black or bright white (so I can have better contrast between board and pieces.) The terminal shows the bright colors as being the color + 8 (so the 8-15 range,) but if I try to use those, I get back `init_pair() returned ERR` (For example, in:)

```
curses.init_pair(1, 0, 15)
```

I also thought that using the `A_BOLD` and <strike>`A_BLINK`</strike> attributes might let me set bright colors in curses, but that doesn't appear to have any effect. For example:

```
pad.addstr(y, x, "qwert", curses.color_pair(1)|curses.A_BOLD)
```

What do I need to do to get these colors?

**Edit:**
It turns out that I had a wrong setting in the terminal ("Use bright colors for bold text" was unchecked,) but I still don't seem to have any way to set a bright background color.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I still don't seem to have any way to set a bright background color.

This question is old, but in case someone will look for answer to it, you just have to combine `curses.A_BOLD` with `curses.A_REVERSE`, for example:

```
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.color_BLACK);
// Pair with green as a foreground color and black as a background
curses.color_pair(1);
// Pair with light green as a background color and black as a foreground
curses.color_pair(1) | curses.A_BOLD | curses.REVERSE;
```

... and now you have 2 × more pairs :)

Comment: This looks like it'll be helpful when I decide to mess with curses again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the issue is simply that I had "Use bright colors for bold text" unchecked (oops, I was messing with the settings for the wrong terminal style.) It is somewhat worrying that I might not be able to rely on users having these settings on Mac OS however.